# lualatex-luatextra math mode issue

Tags: math-mode, luatex, luacode

I'm new here (i.e., pardon my ignorance). But I've been tootling around the LuaLatex and I've come across some bizarre behavior. The following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{luacode*}
function record (m,n)
    file = assert(io.open("test2.dat","a"))
    file:write(string.format("%s %s",m,n),"\n")
end
\end{luacode*}

\newcounter{prob}
\setcounter{prob}{1}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\problem}{m}{%
\noindent \textbf{Problem \theprob:} (#1 points) 
\directlua{record(\theprob ,#1)} \stepcounter{prob}
}

\begin{document}

\problem{2} Who is your Daddy and what does he do?

$42$

\end{document}
```

produces the following error:

```
...MikTex 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2016-06-1 6.lua:10601:
attempt to call field 'suffix' (a nil value).
<to be read again>
relax
1.24 $4
     2$
?
```

Here comes the bizarre part. When the above code is augmented to include anything in math mode before the "problem" command is invoked, everything compiles fine. For example

```
\begin{document}

$ $

\problem{2} Who is your Daddy and what does he do?

$42$

\end{document}
```

compiles with no error. What's the story here? Thanks in advance for your input.

**EDIT**: The issue appears to have something to do with fontspec since replacing the package luatextra with luacode AND fontspec still exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: Dang. Posted a little too soon. If I replace the luatextra package with luacode everything compiles fine. Perhaps the new question should be why is luatextra being fussy.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You are free to delete your question if you think that your question doesn't help anybody else.

Comment: Scratch that. The error (and mysterious fix) persists if fontspec is loaded with luacode. So the issue appears to be more with fontspec (since it is loaded with luatextra).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cut the example down to

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{fontspec}


  \directlua{
function record (m,n)
    file = assert(io.open("test2.dat","a"))
end
}


\begin{document}


\directlua{record(1 ,"x")}

$42$

\end{document}
```

The error is mostly using the variable name `file` if you change that to

```
  zzz = assert(io.open("test2.dat","a"))
```

then it runs without error.

Comment: That works, much obliged!